# install_github crashing my R session

Tags: r, github

I'm trying to install shinyapps from [github](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/blob/master/guide/guide.md). However, every time I run `devtools::install_github('rstudio/shinyapps')`, my R session crashes. I have just installed all the requisite packages so I am sure that I have the latest versions.

It seems that trying to install any packages from github causes the crash

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Edit: Here is the output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252         LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                                LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.2 bitops_1.0-6   devtools_1.5  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     evaluate_0.5.5   ggplot2_1.0.0    grid_3.1.0            gtable_0.1.2     httr_0.3         MASS_7.3-31      memoise_0.2.1    munsell_0.4.2        parallel_3.1.0   plyr_1.8.1      
[13] proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0      whisker_0.3-2 `
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: The error causes the r session to abort, meaning that I have to start a new session. Would it still be informative to include sessionInfo()?

Comment: Yes, get to the same point you were at before it crashed (with any loaded packages, etc.).

Comment: Not able to reproduce on 64-bit Win7 machine on a newer R version. Try updating your R installation to 3.1.1 and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Tried doing that, unfortunately still no luck

Comment: You need the latest version of RCurl - RCurl_1.95-4.2 had some problems.